# Attempting to merge classes using Generics, not working

Tags: c#, generics, serial-port, system.reactive

I have 3 classes that I'd like to talk about merging into a single class.
They're exactly the same with the exception of the `Subscribe` method, more specifically at `observer.OnNext(...)`

I would like to end up with:

```
public class ObservableSerialPort<T> : IObservable<T>, IDisposable
```

which then the instantiation could be:

```
var port = new ObservableSerialPort<byte[]>("COM4");
```

Is this a valid candidate for using `Generics`?

```
public class ObservableSerialPort_bytearray : IObservable<byte[]>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly SerialPort _serialPort;

    public ObservableSerialPort_bytearray(string portName, int baudRate = 9600, Parity parity = Parity.None, int dataBits = 8, StopBits stopBits = StopBits.One)
    {
        _serialPort = new SerialPort()
        {
            PortName = portName,
            BaudRate = baudRate,
            Parity = parity,
            DataBits = dataBits,
            StopBits = stopBits,
            DtrEnable = true,
            RtsEnable = true,
            Encoding = new ASCIIEncoding(),
            ReadBufferSize = 4096,
            ReadTimeout = 10000,
            WriteBufferSize = 2048,
            WriteTimeout = 800,
            Handshake = Handshake.None,
            ParityReplace = 63,
            NewLine = "\n",
        };

        _serialPort.Open();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<byte[]> observer)
    {
        if (observer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("observer");

        // Processing when the incoming event has occurred
        var rcvEvent = Observable.FromEventPattern<SerialDataReceivedEventHandler, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs>(
            h => h.Invoke, h => _serialPort.DataReceived += h, h => _serialPort.DataReceived -= h)
            .Subscribe(e =>
            {
                if (e.EventArgs.EventType == SerialData.Eof)
                {
                    observer.OnCompleted();
                }
                else
                {
                    var buf = new byte[_serialPort.BytesToRead];
                    var len = _serialPort.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

                    // To notify the Observer that it had received data (byte[])
                    Observable.Range(0, len).ForEach(i => observer.OnNext(buf));
                }
            });


        // Processing when an error event occurs
        var errEvent = Observable.FromEventPattern<SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs>
            (h => _serialPort.ErrorReceived += h, h => _serialPort.ErrorReceived -= h)
            .Subscribe(e => observer.OnError(new Exception(e.EventArgs.EventType.ToString())));

        // cancel the event registration When Dispose is called
        return Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            rcvEvent.Dispose();
            errEvent.Dispose();
        });
    }

    public void Send(string text)
    {
        _serialPort.Write(text);
    }

    public void Send(byte[] text)
    {
        _serialPort.Write(text, 0, text.Length);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _serialPort.Close();
    }
}
public class ObservableSerialPort_byte : IObservable<byte>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly SerialPort _serialPort;

    public ObservableSerialPort_byte(string portName, int baudRate = 9600, Parity parity = Parity.None, int dataBits = 8, StopBits stopBits = StopBits.One)
    {
        _serialPort = new SerialPort()
        {
            PortName = portName,
            BaudRate = baudRate,
            Parity = parity,
            DataBits = dataBits,
            StopBits = stopBits,
            DtrEnable = true,
            RtsEnable = true,
            Encoding = new ASCIIEncoding(),
            ReadBufferSize = 4096,
            ReadTimeout = 10000,
            WriteBufferSize = 2048,
            WriteTimeout = 800,
            Handshake = Handshake.None,
            ParityReplace = 63,
            NewLine = "\n",
        };

        _serialPort.Open();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<byte> observer)
    {
        if (observer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("observer");

        // Processing when the incoming event has occurred
        var rcvEvent = Observable.FromEventPattern<SerialDataReceivedEventHandler, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs>(
            h => h.Invoke, h => _serialPort.DataReceived += h, h => _serialPort.DataReceived -= h)
            .Subscribe(e =>
            {
                if (e.EventArgs.EventType == SerialData.Eof)
                {
                    observer.OnCompleted();
                }
                else
                {
                    var buf = new byte[_serialPort.BytesToRead];
                    var len = _serialPort.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

                    // To notify the Observer that it had received data one byte at a time
                    Observable.Range(0, len).ForEach(i => observer.OnNext(buf[i]));
                }
            });


        // Processing when an error event occurs
        var errEvent = Observable.FromEventPattern<SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs>
            (h => _serialPort.ErrorReceived += h, h => _serialPort.ErrorReceived -= h)
            .Subscribe(e =>
                {
                    observer.OnError(new Exception(e.EventArgs.EventType.ToString()));
                });

        // cancel the event registration When Dispose is called
        return Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            rcvEvent.Dispose();
            errEvent.Dispose();
        });
    }

    public void Send(string text)
    {
        _serialPort.Write(text);
    }
    public void Send(byte[] text)
    {
        _serialPort.Write(text, 0, text.Length);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _serialPort.Close();
    }
}
public class ObservableSerialPort_string : IObservable<string>, IDisposable
{
    internal readonly SerialPort _serialPort;

    public ObservableSerialPort_string(string portName, int baudRate = 19200, Parity parity = Parity.None, int dataBits = 8, StopBits stopBits = StopBits.One)
    {
        _serialPort = new SerialPort()
        {
            PortName = portName,
            BaudRate = baudRate,
            Parity = parity,
            DataBits = dataBits,
            StopBits = stopBits,
            DtrEnable = true,
            RtsEnable = true,
            Encoding = new ASCIIEncoding(),
            ReadBufferSize = 4096,
            ReadTimeout = 10000,
            WriteBufferSize = 2048,
            WriteTimeout = 800,
            Handshake = Handshake.None,
            ParityReplace = 63,
            NewLine = "\n",
        };

        _serialPort.Open();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<string> observer)
    {
        if (observer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("observer");

        // Processing when the incoming event has occurred
        var rcvEvent = Observable.FromEventPattern<SerialDataReceivedEventHandler, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs>(h => h.Invoke, h => _serialPort.DataReceived += h, h => _serialPort.DataReceived -= h)
            .Select(e =>
            {
                if (e.EventArgs.EventType == SerialData.Eof)
                {
                    observer.OnCompleted();
                    return string.Empty;
                }

                // And converting the received data to a string
                var buf = new byte[_serialPort.BytesToRead];
                _serialPort.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf);
            })
            .Scan(Tuple.Create(new List<string>(), ""),
                  (t, s) =>
                  {
                      // I linked this time of received data s and the last remaining t.Item2.
                      var source = String.Concat(t.Item2, s);

                      // Minute to put in Item1 a newline code is attached, to notify the Observer.
                      // Amount of line feed code is not attached was placed in Item2, and processed when receiving the next data.
                      var items = source.Split('\n');
                      return Tuple.Create(items.Take(items.Length - 1).ToList(), items.Last());
                  })
            .SelectMany(x => x.Item1) // The Item1 only I will notify the Observer.
            .Subscribe(observer);

        // Processing when an error event occurs
        var errEvent = Observable.FromEventPattern<SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs>(h => _serialPort.ErrorReceived += h, h => _serialPort.ErrorReceived -= h)
            .Subscribe(e => observer.OnError(new Exception(e.EventArgs.EventType.ToString())));

        // cancel the event registration When Dispose is called
        return Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            rcvEvent.Dispose();
            errEvent.Dispose();
        });
    }

    public void Send(string text)
    {
        _serialPort.Write(text);
    }
    public void Send(byte[] text)
    {
        _serialPort.Write(text, 0, text.Length);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _serialPort.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: The problem lays in the returning of data ".Subscribe(e =>..."

Comment: Way too much unnecessary code for this question. And why is this tagged System.Reactive? It's essentially just a question about generics. In the future, I'd recommend creating an abstract program to discuss these kinds of questions rather than tagging specific technologies. If you can't tell the difference then perhaps you should read about generics before attempting to use it.

Comment: SO suggested the tags.  Thanks for your suggestions David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly "no", this is not a valid candidate for using generics, but qualified to "somewhat" because of the presence of a generic interface implemented by all three classes - `IObservable<T>`.

[An Introduction to C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx) says:

> Generics allow you to define type-safe data structures, without
>   committing to actual data types. This results in a significant
>   performance boost and higher quality code, because you get to reuse
>   data processing algorithms without duplicating type-specific code.

Here you *are* unavoidably type committed to (three specific) data types, and the code for each type **is not the same** so there's no reuse potential.

There is however an interface implementation which is generic.

Mostly, I believe what you're really looking for is good old-fashioned inheritance, because there *is* plenty of common "boilerplate" code which is in no way generic (type specific) but which is common to all `ObservableSerialPort` classes. Let's start with that.

Move the common code to a new base class:

```
public abstract class ObservableSerialPort : IDisposable
{
    protected readonly SerialPort _serialPort;

    protected ObservableSerialPort(string portName, int baudRate = 9600, Parity parity = Parity.None, int dataBits = 8, StopBits stopBits = StopBits.One)
    {
        _serialPort = new SerialPort()
        {
            // common SerialPort construction code here. Removed to make answer more readable.
        };

        _serialPort.Open();
    }

    public void Send(string text)
    {
        _serialPort.Write(text);
    }

    public void Send(byte[] text)
    {
        _serialPort.Write(text, 0, text.Length);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _serialPort.Close();
    }
}
```

Retain your three classes but as derived classes of the base class with the common code now refactored away:

```
public class ObservableSerialPort_byte : ObservableSerialPort, IObservable<byte>
{
    public ObservableSerialPort_byte(string portName, int baudRate = 9600, Parity parity = Parity.None, int dataBits = 8, StopBits stopBits = StopBits.One)
    : base(portName, baudRate, parity, dataBits, stopBits) { }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<byte> observer)
    {
```

On a second wave of refactoring we could then get a bit closer to what you asked for by changing the base class definition to:

```
public abstract class ObservableSerialPort<T> : IDisposable, IObservable<T>
```

and adding to the base class:

```
public abstract IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer);
```

First derived class is now:

```
public class ObservableSerialPort_bytearray : ObservableSerialPort<byte[]>
{
    public ObservableSerialPort_bytearray(string portName, int baudRate = 9600, Parity parity = Parity.None, int dataBits = 8, StopBits stopBits = StopBits.One)
    : base(portName, baudRate, parity, dataBits, stopBits) { }

    public override IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<byte[]> observer)
    {
```

And the second is:

```
public class ObservableSerialPort_byte : ObservableSerialPort<byte>
{
    public ObservableSerialPort_byte(string portName, int baudRate = 9600, Parity parity = Parity.None, int dataBits = 8, StopBits stopBits = StopBits.One)
    : base(portName, baudRate, parity, dataBits, stopBits) { }

    public override IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<byte> observer)
    {
```

On top of that, there is some code in `Subscribe()` which is common (not generic) so you could refactor that into a protected function in the base class too.

Note, technically you *could* make a single generic class which checks which of the three concrete types T is, but a) there is no suitable `where` constraint for that so you could in fact instantiate with other, invalid, types such as, say, double and b) you'd then have to perform type comparisons which isn't generic at all and would be totally pointless. Going back to the original quote, doing it that way would not be freeing you from committing to actual data types, would not give you higher quality code, and would offer no further reuse of data processing algorithms without duplicating type-specific code than my first solution above. The same criticism might be levelled at my second solution but I think we can get away with that if the base class is required to implement `IObservable<T>`.

Comment: Thanks Stephen!  This was a very helpful response and did solve my concern(s).

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think generics are appropriate here - at least not as a means to simplify that code. I think you need to have a bit of a tidy up. Your classes are doing too much. If I were you, I would introduce:

```
class ObservableSerialPortReader : IObservable<byte>
```

This would be returned via a factory method so that you can make it singleton per serial port - you don't want more than one reader of your serial port. This class should encapsulate the basic read functionality and should probably publish to allow multiple subscribers to the hot byte stream.

Now you can create Rx operators that consume this byte stream and parse it into higher abstractions. e.g. you might have something like:

```
IObservable<string> GetSerialDeviceMessage(IObservable<byte> serialPortBytes);
IObservable<byte[]> GetSerialDeviceData(IObservable<byte> serialPortBytes,
                                        long numBytes);
```

etc. This is how I would handle getting different data types out of the serial port - note the subscriptions to these can be short-lived without affecting the underlying `ObservableSerialPortReader`. e.g. You might subscribe to `GetSerialDeviceMessage` and it would `OnNext` a single string and then `OnComplete` without affecting the underlying hot stream.

Then, entirely separately create a `class SerialPortWriter`. You could follow the same pattern of this just handling sending bytes, and then being wrapped by classes managing higher abstractions such as sending text commands.

Now you can compose the above classes into top-level abstractions that coordinate them to manage reading and writing. This would for instance, use the above components to subscribe to an appropriate parser, send a message and wait for a response. I can see that sort of exchange being wrapped in a single `async` method.

I would think you'll get clearer more reusable and testable code this way.

Comment: Thanks James!  This is an extremely useful response / guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it means that part of the implementation *won't* be generic. It will have to be provided by the caller, or you'll have to have some "stock" implementations for known types.

Here's a simple example:

```
abstract class Base<T>
{
    public abstract T Decode(byte[] input);
}

class StringDecoder : Base<string>
{
    public override string Decode(byte[] input)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(input);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could pass the implementation as a delegate:

```
class GenericDecoder<T>
{
    private Func<byte[], T> _decoder;

    public GenericDecoder(Func<byte[], T> decoder)
    {
        _decoder = decoder;
    }

    public T Decode(byte[] input)
    {
        return _decoder(input);
    }
}
```

Initialized like this:

```
new GenericDecoder<string>(x => Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x))
```

Now, all that said: before you do anything like the above, you should be very sure you really need this to be generic.

A reason to do that would be, for example, if the base class actually needed to manipulate items of the generic type parameter's type, store them in a member array, etc. But even there, composition might be a better strategy. I.e. have a non-generic class specific to each type being used, which *contains* an instance of the generic type, to which it delegates certain operations supported by that generic type.

Your code example is not simple enough for it to be readily apparent (i.e. without some time-consuming analysis) what the exact need is here. But it's possible that all you really need is a non-generic base class providing the core implementation details, sub-classed by type-specific non-generic classes to handle those type-specific parts of the operation.